# C# - Compare two List<T> Objects if keypairs are equal

Tags: c#, performance, list, compare

I have got two `List<T>` objects. It is filled with objects of my own class `iFile`, which contains a file path and the last edited date from the last call of the program.
Now I want to compare these two Lists, but my current code is running quite too slow! (4min for ~70.000 entries)

Here's my code:

```
private static List<iFile> compareLists(List<iFile> old)
{
    List<iFile> cf = new List<iFile>();
    foreach(iFile file in files)
    {
        bool notChanged = false;

        iFile oldFile = files.Where(f => f.fPath == file.fPath).FirstOrDefault();
        if(oldFile != null & oldFile.lastChange.Equals(file.lastChange))
        {
            notChanged = true;
        }
        if(!notChanged)
        {
            cf.Add(file);
        }
    }
    return cf;
}
```

What would you suggest to change to get better performance results?

Comment: what is `files` in this scenario?

Comment: You could turn your iFile object into a dictionary<string, datetime> with the path as the key. Then you can do a lookup on the dictionary which should be O(1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join files by `fPath`. That will internally use hash set to find matches between two collections. Unlike simple `Where` search which has complexity O(N), search in hash set has O(1) complexity:

```
var modifiedFiles = from file in files
                    join oldFile in old on file.fPath equals oldFile.fPath
                    where oldFile.lastChange != file.lastChange
                    select file;

return modifiedFiles.ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! Worked fine, just took 2sec.. I'm impressed!